# Pass ColdFusion variable through HTML hidden input

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion, captcha

I'm making a CAPTCHA for some ColdFusion forms and I can't understand why this isn't working.

```
<cfimage action="captcha" width="300" height="75" text="#captcha#">         
<input type="hidden" name="captchaHash" value="#captchaHash#">
```

The above is the code I'm using to create the CAPTCHA within the cfform.

```
<cfset captcha = makeRandomString()>
<cfset captchaHash = hash(captcha)>
```

Those are the variables that I set when my form loads. I can put the function, makeRandomString on here but it shouldn't have any bearing on my problem.

Basically, for whatever reason when I process the form the hashed captcha value in the hidden input is not carrying over. I've output it to the screen on the process page and it just says #captchaHash# rather than the hashed value of the captcha. If I output it to the screen on the form page itself before it is processed it works fine. So, I was hoping that somebody could help me pass my captchaHash value from my cfset to my hidden input and solve this stupid problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like missing cfoutput tags.  What happens when you cfdump the form scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you posted it sounds like you just need to wrap the variable in a cfoutput tag to get it to work.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us. Good luck!